# Why is the constructor called twice in C++?

Tags: c++, templates

In this code the constructor is called twice.

How do I avoid that?

If I uncomment the default constructor code block then code does not give satisfactory output..

And I also want conditional based instantiation of template so I used void pointer.

```
#include<iostream.h>
template<class Type>
class Data{
      public:
      Type val;
      Data(Type v){
                cout<<"In Constructor Param";
                val = v;
      }
      Data(){
             //  cout<<"In Constructor Defa";  uncommnet this line
      }
      ~Data(){}
};
int main(){
    Data<void *> obj;
    obj = new Data<float>(31.34f);
    cout<<*(float*)obj.val;
}
```

Output:

```
In Constructor Param
In Constructor Param
31.34
```

Thanks for involving.

Comment: Unsure how this code compiles.

Comment: Cause you called it 2 times in C++.

Comment: @DeadMG: If you mean because the _new-expression_ is being assigned to an object, it compiles because the object type has a conversion constructor that takes `void*` (and therefore any object pointer). The code is well-formed, the memory leak and obsolete header notwithstanding.

Comment: @Mike: Well-formed syntactically, but it exhibits undefined behaviour. See my answer.

Comment: @Xeo: In C++03, it was undefined since such conversions were only defined for POD types, and this isn't quite POD. In C++11, they are well defined for any standard-layout type, including this one. I've no idea what the rules were for whatever ancient dialect is being used here, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are creating three objects. Your code contains an implicit conversion from `Data<float>*` to `Data<void*>`, via the conversion constructor `Data<void*>::Data(void*)`, and is equivalent to

```
Data<void *> obj;                              // first object
Data<float> * temp = new Data<float>(31.34f);  // second object
obj = Data<void *>((void*)temp);               // third (temporary) object
```

I've no idea how to avoid that, because I've no idea what your code is trying to do. You could prevent weird conversions like that by declaring the constructor `explicit`, so that it doesn't allow implicit conversions.

Also, whichever book you're using to learn C++ is very outdated. Since 1998 (and possibly earlier), the standard I/O header has been called `<iostream>` with no `.h`, and all the standard library's names like `cout` have been in `namespace std`.

Comment: I am using Turbo c++
I want to create array of template **class Data** and each of array element containing different Datatype

Comment: @MaheshMeniya: You can't do that with templates - each element of an array must be the same type, and different template specialisations are different types. You'll need either dynamic polymorphism (i.e. store pointers to a base class, and access the objects via virtual functions or RTTI), or a polymorphic wrapper like `boost::variant` or `boost::any` , although I doubt that will work on your prehistoric compiler. If you want others to help, it would be a very good idea to learn modern C++, with a modern compiler - there aren't many people who can remember much about Turbo C++.

Answer (score 6):

The first call should be obvious: is in the call to `new Data<float>(31.34f)`.

The second one is in a temporary object of type `Data<void*>` that is constructed in the next line. Your code is equivalent to the following:

```
Data<void *> obj;
Data<float> *t1 = new Data<float>(31.34f); //first!
void *t2 = t1;
Data<void *> t3(t2);  //second!
Data<void *> t4(t3); //copy constructor (elided)
obj = t4;  //operator=
cout<<*(float*)obj.val;
```

It is worth noting that the last line does a cast that is not probably what you want. That would be:

```
cout << ((Data<float*>)obj.val).val;
```

Or similar.

Comment: It's actually `Data<void*> t3 = t2`, it's an implicit conversion. If the `Type` constructor of `Data` was marked `explicit`, the OP's code would fail to compile.

Comment: @Xeo - I stand corrected! But that syntax adds yet another temporal, constructed with `t2` and used to copy-construct `t3`, although most likely elided by the compiler.

Comment: No, it is exactly the same, only that `T o1(o2);` allows explicit conversion and `T o1 = o2;` only allows implicit conversion. Also, the second form does *not* call `operator=`.

Comment: @Xeo - I think that you are wrong. The call to `operator=` is not done because the compiler is using _copy elision_. But it is still needed and the access checked. You can test it by adding a private `operator=(const Data&)` to the class: it will fail to compile.

Comment: No, `obj = t4` will fail to compile. `Data<void*> t4 = t3;` will not fail and will not call `operator=`.

Comment: @Xeo - My mistake: when I say `operator=` I mean _copy constructor_.  That is, `T o1 = o2` is equivalent to `T o1(T(o2))`. So if the copy constructor is private it will not compile. See the showcase [here](http://ideone.com/DdPmW). The problem with your code is that you use the same type for `o1` and `o2`.

Answer (score 5):

The compiler implicitly declares a copy constructor for you. Next, your `Data` is implicitly convertible from `Type`, which in case of `void*` is implicitly convertible from any other pointer. Let's break this down:

```
Data<void*> obj;
Data<float>* new_obj = new Data<float>(31.34f); // your call to new
                       // the constructor is called the first time here
void* conv1 = new_obj; // implicit conversion to void*
Data<void*> conv2 = conv1; // implicit conversion from 'Type' (aka 'void*')
                           // the constructor is called the second time here
obj = conv2; // copy constructor
```

Also, the line `cout<<*(float*)obj.val;` is invoking **undefined behaviour** in C++98/03 (and your compiler seems to be much older than that), as your `val` *actually* is a `Data<float>*`, and not a `float*`. You should have that as

```
cout << static_cast<Data<float>*>(obj.val)->val;
```

Comment: @Xeo: Actually it's *not* undefined in C++11; converting between a pointer to a standard-layout class and a pointer to its first member is well defined. Not that I'm suggesting anyone should so that.

Comment: @Mike: Ah, yeah, standard-layout. I'm still not too familiar with the new C++11 classifications. I added a remark for C++98/03. However, this is extremely brittle, since you don't cast from `Data<float>*` to `float*`, but go through `void*`.

Answer (score 4):

`Data<void *> obj;` constructs a Data object to store `void *` type using the parameterized constructor passing `new Data` as the parameter value. `obj` itself needs to be a pointer:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    Data<float> *obj = new Data<float>(31.34f);
    std::cout << obj->val;
}
```

Your version is equivalent to:

```
Data<void *> objs; // no param constructor
/* Data<float>(31.34f); param constructor */
obj = Data<void *>(new Data<float>(31.34f)); // param constructor
```